# Are there any pairs of functions where $g(n,x)=f^{(n)}(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Are there any **non-piecewise** pairs of functions that satisfy this quality?

> $g(n,x)=f^{(n)}(x)$
>
> Where $n\in \Bbb{Z}$ and is the $n^{th}$ derivitive of $f(x)$

This is a long shot but I'm just curious

Comment: $f = 0$, $g = 0$?

Comment: There are lots of examples.  For instance, $f(x)=x^2$ and$$g(n,x)=\cases{x^2&if $n=0$\cr 2x&if $n=1$\cr2&if $n=2$\cr0&if $n>2$.\cr}$$But perhaps this is not really what you wanted, in which case you will need to ask a more precise question.

Comment: I was hoping for  non-piecewise functions @David

Comment: I thought so (comment posted before your edit).  See my answer.

Comment: The main part of this [book](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_27%3AMhenni%20Benghorbal)  is devoted for solving your problem and beyond that!

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)=\sin x$ and
$$g(n,x)=\sin\Bigl(x+\frac{n\pi}2\Bigr)\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Take any infinitely continuously differentiable and integrable $f\in C^{\infty}$ and define $g(n,x) := f^{(n)}(x)$.

Comment: $f\in C^{\infty}\rightarrow $ derivatives are continuous.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yes. That's just an explanation of the notation, not an additional requirement.

Comment: I don't really understand this @AndrewMiloradovsky. What does $f\in C^{\infty}$ mean?

Comment: @samarbarrett Continuity class. That function $f$ has derivatives of any degree, so that the expression $f^{(n)}$ make sense. And additionally, since $n$ in your question may be negative, $f$ also has to have anti-derivatives (indefinite integrals) of any degree. There are many examples.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky Okay, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define g(y, x) to be the fractional derivative of order y of f, evaluated at x. See wikipedia for more on fractional derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)
= e^{ax}$.

$g(n, x)
=a^n e^{ax}
= a^n f(x)
$.

$a$ can be complex as well as real.